# Error handling in the values in a class constructor

Tags: python, class, error-handling

I have a simple class defined as follows:

```
class SimpleClass():

    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
```

What is the best way to ensure that `n` and `m` are positive and `m` is less than `n**2`? Should I use an `if-statement` with a message? Is there any other particular pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: What should happen if they aren't positive?

Comment: @sj95126 If they are not positive there will be a ValueError in another function of the class. I do not know what is the best practice in such cases.

Comment: just create some `@staticmethod` called `is_positive` and give it one paramtere which is the number, and it checks the number and raises a value error if it's below 0, then just do `self.n = self.is_positive(n)` and so on

Comment: speaking about readability tho, arguably it would be better to name that method something else because normally a function name that starts with `is` should return a boolean value so maybe name that method something like `check_positive` or `kill_negatives` or `raise_error_for_negative_numbers` or something else, but unfortunately I can't come up with anything better (albeit I feel like there is a better name for this)

Comment: @matiis If in addition want to check `m` to be less than `n**2` how could I include it in a `@staticmethod`?

Comment: This is a really simple check, just use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ordinary `if` statements.

```
class SimpleClass():

    def __init__(self, n, m):
        if n <= 0:
            raise ValueError('n must be positive')
        if m <= 0 or m >= n**2:
            raise ValueError('m must be between 0 and n**2')
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
```